# How to clear the VS Code debug cache?

Tags: debugging, caching, visual-studio-code

When I run my server.js from the command line everything works fine, but when I run it from the VS Code debugger, I get an older cached version of my graphql types. I'm assuming this is a cache issue, is there a way to clear it?

Here is my launch.json in case it's useful:

```
{

  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Backend Debug",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/babel-node",
      "runtimeArgs": ["--nolazy"],
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/server.js",
      "stopOnEntry": false,
      "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "development"
      },
      "console": "internalConsole",
      "sourceMaps": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look in C:\Users{your id}\AppData\Local\Microsoft for a cache. I have found nine caching locations related to Microsoft VS and others.

I get different results in css settings starting VS in debug vs non-debug mode.   VS Code produces correct results.  Restart does not even resolve differences.